# OwnerSharingRules removed from Summer 15 API

Tags: deployment, sharing, migration-tool

As stated here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_ownersharingrule.htm

OwnerSharingRules have been removed from the API. For example, the folder customObjectSharingRules in eclipse now just shows empty files after doing a refresh from the Org.

This makes it imposible to deploy sharing rules using eclipse or the ant migration tool. Is there a new way to deploy this metadata?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's been replaced by a very similar object called `SharingOwnerRule`.

Docs [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_sharingrules.htm#SharingOwnerRule)

> SharingOwnerRule
>   Defines a ownership-based sharing rule. It extends SharingBaseRule and inherits all its fields. Available in API version 33.0 and later.

**EDIT**
Here is what the package.xml data looks like (you can't use a wildcard, according to [salesforce](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_types_list.htm))

```
<types>
    <members>MyFirstRule</members>
    <members>MySecondRule</members>
    <name>AccountOwnerSharingRule</name>
</types>
```

Comment: You are right, however, this doesn't seem to be supported by neither eclipse or mavensmate.

Comment: You mean you can't download this metadata? If so, just the developer console to develop this feature. Also, if this answer is correct, you can accept it and or upvote.

Comment: I'd upvote but don't have enough rep yet :-),  still, I consider the question not answered as there seems to be no way to retrieve this metadata in order to track changes in git and deploy to other orgs using Ant Migration Tool or Eclipse.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I wonder if we have a bug on our hands? I specified the correct xml as added above, but it failed to pull anything.